I am trying to upload a file on s3 using streamlit app but I am getting an error filename must be a path

I have tried printing the path and have found out that streamlit
stores files temporarily but I haven't been able to get the path where
the temp file is stored
I am unable to get the path of the file.I even tried printing it but
got no path.I earlier tried to upload by specifying file path from
local machine and the code was working fine

import streamlit as st
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError, PartialCredentialsError,ClientError
import io
import os
import time

def upload_to_s3(file_path,bucket_name,object_name=None):
    
    s3=boto3.client("s3")
    if object_name is None:
        object_name=file_path
    try:
     s3.upload_file(file_path,bucket_name,object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        print("Client error occured {e}")


def main():
    bucket="shellkode1111"
    st.set_page_config(page_title="apptech",layout="wide")
    st.title("Apple")
    uploaded_file=st.file_uploader("Upload file",type=["mp4"])
    s3=boto3.client("s3")
    sts=boto3.client("sts")
    response = s3.head_bucket(Bucket="shellkode1111")
    try:
        s3.upload_file(uploaded_file,bucket,uploaded_file.name)
    except ClientError as e:
        print("Client Error occured {e}")
    print(response)
    bucket="shellkode1111"
    print("------------------------------")
    print(uploaded_file)
    print("----------------------------------")
    print("Working1")
    if(uploaded_file):
        print("Working")
        response=upload_to_s3(uploaded_file,bucket,uploaded_file)


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()



If successful, uploaded_file is an UploadedFile object. This object is a subclass of BytesIO, and can be used wherever a "file-like" object is accepted.
So instead of trying to upload the file from its path, you can use s3.upload_fileobj.

Thank you for the answer.I looked up and found out that for upload_file function file path is necessary and for uploading from memory(RAM) upload_fileobj needs to be used

If you are using uploaded_file, then the file will already be in memory anyway. So you can use upload_fileobj right away.
